# How to create a positive definite matrix with restrictions?

Tags: r, matrix, restriction

Consider that we want to create a covariance matrix of three random variables, `v1, v2, v3`.
Then, the matrix has to satisfy the positive definiteness as well as other covariance restrictions such as positive variances and range of correlation.

Additionally, I want to impose a restriction: `-var(v3) = cov(v2, v3) - cov(v1, v3)`.

For example, I need a matrix like below:

```
> tmp <- matrix(c(1, 0.6, 0.3,
                  0.6, 1, -0.2,
                  0.3, -0.2, 0.5), ncol = 3, byrow = T)
> is.positive.definite(tmp)
[1] TRUE
```

Note that `var(v3) = 0.5, cov(v1, v3) = 0.3, cov(v2, v3) = -0.2` and thus `-var(v3) = cov(v2, v3) - cov(v1, v3)`.

Note also that the variances (diagonal elements) are positive and the correlation coefficients such as `0.3/(1*0.5)` are in [-1,1].

Of course, it is possible to make these matrices manually, but, it is so time-consuming because I have to make about a thousand of this kind of matrices.

Thus, how to make create a positive definite matrix with restrictions?

Comment: "Of course, it is possible to make these matrices manually" How do you do that? I.e., what is the algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way with the **CVXR** package. It does not allow to impose on a variable matrix to be positive definite, only positive semidefinite. So I add a restriction on the determinant. One can only add a restriction on the log-determinant, it should be `log_det(A) > -Inf` but this is not possible so I took `>= 0` (so `det(A) >= 1). Also, one needs an objective. I choose to minimize the norm of` A`. There is an infinity of solutions to your problem so one needs such additional constraints.

```r
library(CVXR)

A <- Variable(3, 3, PSD = TRUE)
constraints <- list(
  A[3,3] == A[1,3] - A[2,3], 
  log_det(A) >= 0
)
objective <- Minimize(norm(A))
prob <- Problem(objective, constraints)
sol <- psolve(prob, solver = "SCS")
sol$getValue(A)
```

Comment: Laurent Great! It is what I wanted to know exactly!

Comment: Additionally, I found that the code you wrote generates a matrix, but I want to make several matrices. How to do this?

Comment: @MinChulPark You mean several matrices with the same constraint? I don't know, choose another constraint on `log_det(A)` maybe.